# Parse JSON url with basic auth?

Tags: jquery, json, api, shopify

So I recently learned how to parse a JSON file locally. However with the database I'm working with, the JSON file is sure to expand overtime. I am trying to collect Shopify customers with their API. I am also using NextJS, TypeScript, and TailwindCSS to create a database which will take this information. What I want to do is parse the information through this URL https://---------.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/customers.json which asks for a username and password. The tutorials I find online aren't too helpful.. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Is it using HTTP Basic Auth? If so, you can provide a Username/Password by doing `https://username:password@---------.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/customers.json`.

Comment: I am a little new to this to tell you the truth. I am using Postman. It just says Basic Auth. I'll give your solution a shot though, thanks.